# EmberJS: Jquery datepicker stays active when changing routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, datepicker

I have an emberjs web app where one of my views is a search page to query a database of records. I have the ability to filter by date and am using JQuery's datepicker.

The problem I am having is that if a user opens the datepicker and then hits either the browser back or forward button it stays active on the screen until a user clicks away. To clarify the process is as below:

1. Navigate to search page
2. Click select date
3. Datepicker appears
4. User clicks the browsers back button
5. Previous page loads BUT with datepicker still lingering around

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to hide or destroy the datepicker when a browsers back button is pressed?

Thanks!!

EDIT----------------------------
Current code:

Formal.Route.Search = Ember.Route.extend({

```
    deactivate: function () {
        console.log("hi");
        $("ui-datepicker-div").datepicker("destroy");

    },
```

Comment: EDIT: I'm using deactivate to detect the route change but how do I clear the datepicker from view? Thanks!

Comment: Wast just going to say that, you can call; `$(".selector" ).datepicker( "destroy" );` or similar

Comment: When I hit the back button it doesn't seem to destroy the datepicker still. Pardon the noob question but ".selector" should be the elements ID correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the removal logic at View instead Route. Lets assume your template name is "search", then

```
App.SearchView=Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement:function(){
       $("#ui-datepicker-div").datepicker();
    },
    willDestroyElement:function()){
       $("#ui-datepicker-div").datepicker("destroy");
    }
});
```

Note: I assumed your selector is ID, if it is css class then use $(".ui-datepicker-div")

If you would like to write datepicker as component which can be used across the application then do watch the Screencast here http://eviltrout.com/2014/06/03/jquery-component.html

P.S. If you still could not figure out, please show your code in http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Great call moving to the view. Helped me track down the root cause and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your help!

I resolved the issue with the following:

```
Formal.View.Datepicker = Ember.TextField.extend({
   destroyDatepicker: function () {
        this.$().datepicker("hide");
    },
});
```

For some reason "destroy" was not doing the trick but "hide" does. If anyone has any insight into why this is I'd love to hear.